# Add an item to a drop down list which is bound dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm binding my Drop Down List to a DataSource Dynamically as follows:

```
DDLRecordStatus.DataSource = BLREOptions.getRecordStatusList();
DDLRecordStatus.DataTextField = "OptionName";
DDLRecordStatus.DataValueField = "OptionValue";
DDLRecordStatus.DataBind();
```

However, the datasource does not contain a null or empty option, I need to add an item Name " "(Blank) and with value -1 to the Drop Down List that appears as the first choice, is this possible ?

Comment: You can call `DDLRecordStatus.Items.Insert` after `DataBind` call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this is possible, you just need to insert it manually after data binding is done:

```
DDLRecordStatus.DataBind();
DDLRecordStatus.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" ", "-1"));
```

Alternatively you can specify it directly in the markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLRecordStatus"
     ...
     AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text=" " Value="-1" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Notice `AppendDataBoundItems` property, which makes sure default list item is not erased.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly, There is only one edit to the code above : DDLRecordStatus.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" ", "-1")); (missing "Items")

Answer (score 1):

Insert the record into the list before binding to the control. I'll just assume the class is called `Status`:

```
var statusList = BLREOptions.getRecordStatusList();
statusList.Insert(0, new Status { OptionName = "", OptionValue = -1 });

DDLRecordStatus.DataSource = statusList;
```